# Enable updatedb for mlocate in CentOS or RHEL

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, locate

Even if the `mlocate` package is installed with `dnf install mlocate` the `updatedb` command is not scheduled to run.

That means `locate <filename>` return empty results.

How do you enable `updatedb` to be run automatically without creating your own scripts or cron jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mlocate` package shipped with CentOS Stream 8 or RHEL 8 does not automatically start or schedule the `updatedb` command during package installation.

The installation package ships with a [SystemD timer unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) which you have to manually `enable`, which in turn runs the `mlocate-updatedb.service`. The timer replaces traditional `cron` jobs for `updatedb`.

Enabling the timer will start the service immediately:

```bash
systemctl enable mlocate-updatedb.timer
```

To start the updatedb process manually, i.e. if you have done major changes, you can run:

```bash
systemctl start mlocate-updatedb.service
```